# How to extract image from embedded resource programmatically in VB .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, resources

I have a small vb.net app that have a few images in an embedded resource.

Is there a way I could extract one of those images to a folder **from the same exe that contains the** resource?, like clicking a button, selecting a folder to save it and extracting the image there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource images can just be saved from the exe.  Use a "SaveFileDialog" control to get the filename.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub SaveFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles SaveFileDialog1.FileOk
    My.Resources.Image2.Save(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif)
End Sub
```

Comment: EDIT: Added example for SaveFileDialog control